# Using Join, Merge, Dissolve in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am new to QGIS.

I have two layers:

Layer A: Large polygons joining areas, lets call them countries.

Layer B: Smaller polygons(States) containing population count data within the large areas(countries).

I would like to summate all the state count data for each country.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user be sure to take the (Tour)[http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in QGIS using the tool DISSOLVE WITH STATS

it can be found here https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DissolveWithStats/